# How to get account name using Amazon Advertising Api V2?

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I am using Amazon advertising api version V2. According to the  [https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/reference/profiles], the get profile api gives account name. But I am not getting name in account details. Following is the response I am getting:

```
[
    {
        "profileId": "**********",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "dailyBudget": 2.0,
        "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "accountInfo": {
            "marketplaceStringId": "*********",
            "id": "***********",
            "type": "seller"
        }
    }
]
```

How can I get account name from api ?

Comment: Can I somehow get amazon profile name with advertising api v2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get profile name from amazon api with list profiles or get profiles. It only gives brand name for Sponsored Brands.

Comment: @deepa-varma list or get profiles is independent from the campaign type.

Answer (score 2):

You can get user_id, name and email by sending this request:

```
GET https://api.amazon.com/user/profile
```

Headers should include your Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId.
And the client should granted you access to the scope 'profile' (additionally to the default 'cpc_advertising:campaign_management').

EDIT:
<s>Profile names are only available for profiles of type 'vendor' or 'agency' via /profiles endpoint.

See: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/2/profiles#/Profiles/listProfiles</s>
this has changed: names are also shown for 'seller' profiles now

Comment: this api request is not a request to the advertising api - that's why it is not documented in the advertising api documentation i guess

Comment: This actually just returns the authorized user's account name.

Comment: @molta yes, this returns user_id, name and email of the user's account name. Profile names are only available for profiles of type 'vendor' or 'agency' via `/profiles` endpoint

Comment: Yes, my point was, though, is that if you are auth'ing as an agency, or just someone who has access to many advertising accounts, the name will be the name of the user who had authed, and not the name of the profile.

Comment: Yeah, i think the naming is not good at all. Even the API domain is different: 

`https://api.amazon.com/user/profile` -> profile name of the amazon user
`https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/profiles` -> profiles of given advertising account